# POST request in newman fails if form-data has more than one file attached

Tags: spring-boot, postman, multipartform-data, attachment, newman

I am running this POST request in Newman.

Request runs fine if there is a single file attached.

But it fails if there are 2 files attached.

[image]

The request fails with file load error:

[image]

I cannot explain this? (I am using a Spring Boot environment)

Comment: please add what do you want, what did you write in the code and where is it failing. Those will help to investigate further

Comment: Really upload file exists in that location. location might be wrong - that is why we are facing "no such file" error.

Answer (score 0):

Upload File via newman :

1. Place your **collection** file and **upload** **file** in **same location**.
2. Open your exact collection via **notepad++** or any
3. Go to the **Body** of your request
4. Change the file location **(src)** to "./[filename.txt]"

   "body": {
   "mode": "formdata",
   "formdata": [
   {
   "key": "black door",
   "type": "file",
   **"src": "./file.csv"**
   }
   ]
   }

[image]